# Solidity constructor declaration and statements between function signature and visibility modifieres

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I just came across this in a Solidity contract, I don't understand it. Specifically I don't understand how there can be a function call after the constructor parameters block. If it were a modifier, it would be after "public", but it is immediately after the parameters. What does `MerkleTreeWithHistory(_merkleTreeHeight)` mean in this context?

```
  constructor(
    IVerifier _verifier,
    uint256 _denomination,
    uint32 _merkleTreeHeight,
    address _operator
  ) MerkleTreeWithHistory(_merkleTreeHeight) public {
    require(_denomination > 0, "denomination should be greater than 0");
    verifier = _verifier;
    operator = _operator;
    denomination = _denomination;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MerkleTreeWithHistory(_merkleTreeHeight)
```

Calls the parent contract constructor. It is executed before entering the sub-contract constructor.